# How to prevent user from entering specific keys in chrome?

Tags: jquery

I have used following jQuery function to prevent user from entering specific keys,

```
$('#prod_name_en').keypress(function (e) {
if (e.key.match(/[!@#]+/))
    {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

It is working fine in mozilla but not in chrome.

it is throwing following error,

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined

Please help me how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Take a look at https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/15220

Comment: _"It is working fine in mozilla but not in chrome."_ Which version of chrome did you try `js` at?

Comment: chrom version is 50.0.2661.94 m

Comment: @MujahedAKAS Appears to return expected result at chromium 50, `key` is `undefined` at chrome 42. You should be able to use `String.prototype.slice()` to return same results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't rely on JQuery's keyboard event **key** property. It may not work as we expected.
There are two different types of codes: keyboard codes(a number representing the key on the keyboard the user pressed) and character codes(a number representing a Unicode character). IE only stores the character code in `keyCode` while all other browsers store it in `which`. Some(but not all) browsers also store it in `charCode` and/or `keyCode`. 
To get character value - use the character code through the `String.formCharCode` method:

```
$('#prod_name_en').on('keypress', function(e){
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.charCode || e.which; // cross-browser key-code detection
    if (String.fromCharCode(keyCode).match(/[!@#]+/)) e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Can you please explain, what it is really doing?

Comment: I mean why not directly use e.keycode in fromcharcode function?

Comment: @MujahedAKAS, see the added explanation

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){


      $('#prod_name_en').keypress(function (e) {

            // 97 code for a and 98 for b

            if(e.keyCode==97 || e.keyCode==98)
                e.preventDefault();

        });
    });

</script>

<input type="text" id="prod_name_en">
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround using `String.prototype.slice()`, `input` event, `event.target.value`

```js
$("#prod_name_en").on("input", function(e) {
  var value = e.target.value;
  if (value.slice(-1).match(/[!@#]+/g)) {
    e.target.value = value.slice(0, -1);
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input type="text" id="prod_name_en" value="" />
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/4rmsjctf/1/

Comment: if we keep holding shift key and type ! and clicks into other input field than ! remains.

Comment: @MujahedAKAS _"if we keep holding shift key and type ! and clicks into other input field than ! remains."_ Could not reproduce described effect.